# Codename One - Identifying what OS app is running on

Tags: java, codenameone

Is there a way to check within my codes what Os a codename one app is running on, whether its Blackberry, Android, iOS, Windows, Symbian, etc...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally if you want to do that you are probably doing something wrong and should backtrack and rethink "why" you want to do that. There are far better options to get platform specific functionality such as themes, override, native code etc.

You can get this information using `Display.getInstance().getPlatformName()`.

Comment: Hi @Shai Almog. Thanks for the feedback. I dont really need it for a functionality. I am calling an API that requires me to pass a code for RIM, IOS, WIn etc. The API uses that to differentiate the client platform, thats why I needed it. Hope it makes sense?

Comment: That's pretty much the main use case for which we added this method, unfortunately 98% of the people asking about this want to write code such as if(ios) do that... Glad this isn't the case here!

Answer (score 2):

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

More here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: That's for standard Java not for Codename One where underlying VM implementations have some issues with mapping to System.getProperty consistently so unfortunately this will behave erratically.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I was mislead by the 'Java' tag.